# Multilevel reverse lookup using array returned from INDEX-MATCH as keys

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

In my use-case, when I use INDEX-MATCH I get an array.
The array corresponds to some keys in another sheet where the column A are the keys and the next column B are the values. How do I use the returned array of keys and look them up in the other sheet, get the corresponding value, and sum the values?

To make this more concrete:

I have three sheets, weights, bags, and totals.

`weights` has items in column A and their corresponding weight in column B.

[image]

`bags` has each row with the column A as the bag name and all other columns as items in each bag. the items are from `weghts!A1:A`

[image]

`totals` has column A as the name of the bag from `bags` sheet. The second column should be the total weight of all items inside that bag.

[image]

The items themselves can be found in the `bags` sheet using the formula

```
INDEX(bags!B:Z, MATCH(A1, bags!A1:A))
```

How do I use this array of results to find their weights in `weights` and sum them up? I would like to not need to modify the structure of the sheets.

Comment: Excel, or Google sheets?  Either way ,it's useful to show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Google sheets...

Comment: @TimWilliams take a look at the edit, I've elaborated on the question

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(K1:K, IF(D1:D<>"", {D1:D, 
 MMULT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(E1:I, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A), VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(E1:I, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A)), A1:B, 2*SIGN(ROW(A1:A)), 0)&""), E1:I)*1, 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(E1:I))^0)}, ), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]